# Is it possible to go with horizontal scroll and show all (with toggle effect) at the same time on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

```css
.nav-sec{padding:0;background-color:#fff;border-radius:3px;margin-top:20px;box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);position:relative;height:50px;line-height:50px;z-index:994;float:left;width:100%;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;white-space:nowrap;}

.nav-sec a.all{float:left;padding:0 15px;}
.nav-sec a.all span{padding:5px 10px;background-color:#b60001;font-size:15px;color:#fff;border-radius:5px;}
.nav-sec ul.menu-items{padding-left:10px;float:left;height:50px;transition:all ease 0.5s;-webkit-transition:all ease 0.5s;-moz-transition:all ease 0.5s;}
.nav-sec ul.last-itm{float:right;width:50px;text-align:right;}
.nav-sec ul.last-itm ul{float:left;text-align:left;margin-top:-2px;}
.nav-sec ul.last-itm ul li:first-child a{padding-left:0;}
.nav-sec ul.last-itm li{display:inline-block;float:none;}
.nav-sec ul.last-itm li a{padding-right:15px;}
.nav-sec ul li{display:inline-block;float:none;}
.nav-sec ul li:nth-last-child(2){display:none;}
.nav-sec ul li a[href="#menu-open"]:hover span, .nav-sec ul li a[href="#menu-closed"]:hover span{background-color:transparent;color:#000}


.nav-sec ul li:last-child{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;padding:0px;}
.nav-sec ul li.last i{color:#b60001;}
.nav-sec ul li a{display:block;padding:0 5px;color:#000;}
.nav-sec ul li a.active span{background-color:#b60001;color:#fff;position:relative;}
.nav-sec ul li a.active span:after{ top: 100%;left: 50%;border: solid transparent;content: " ";height: 0;width: 0;
position: absolute;pointer-events: none;border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);border-top-color: #b60001;border-width: 6px;margin-left: -6px;}
.nav-sec ul li a:hover span{}
.nav-sec ul li a:hover span{background-color:#b60001;color:#fff;}
.nav-sec ul li a span{padding:5px 10px;font-size:15px;color:#000;border-radius:5px;transition:all ease 0.5s;}
.nav-sec ul .nav-drop{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:50px;background-color:#fff;padding-left:0;border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;padding:0 15px;}
.nav-sec#menu-open{height:50px;transition:all ease 0.5s;-webkit-transition:all ease 0.5s;-moz-transition:all ease 0.5s;}
.nav-sec#menu-open:target {height: 100px;padding: 0;}
.nav-sec#menu-open:target ul {max-height: none;}
.nav-sec#menu-open:target a {display: block;}
.nav-sec#menu-open:target a:hover {background-color:transparent;color:#9f0606;}
.nav-sec#menu-open:target li:last-child {display: none;}
.nav-sec#menu-open:target li:nth-last-child(2) {display: inline-block;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;margin: 0;}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="nav-sec" id="menu-open">
     
     <ul class="menu-items" id="menu-closed">
      
      <li><a href="#" class="active"><span>All</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>MBA</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Bank-PO</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>GK</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Interview</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Miscellaneous</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Vocab</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Academic Zone</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training1</span></a></li> 
      <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training2</span></a></li> 
      <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training3</span></a></li> 
      <li><a href="#menu-closed"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span></a></li> 
      <li><a href="#menu-open"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span></a></li> 
     </ul>

    </div>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

```css
.nav-sec {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 994;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target .menu-items {
  white-space: normal;
}

.nav-sec a.all {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.nav-sec a.all span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #b60001;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-sec ul.menu-items {
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.nav-sec ul.last-itm ul li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-sec ul.last-itm li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.nav-sec ul.last-itm li a {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.nav-sec ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.nav-sec ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

.nav-sec ul li a[href="#menu-open"]:hover span,
.nav-sec ul li a[href="#menu-closed"]:hover span {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000
}

.nav-sec ul li:last-child {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: sticky;
}

.nav-sec ul li.last i {
  color: #b60001;
}

.nav-sec ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #000;
}

.nav-sec ul li a.active span {
  background-color: #b60001;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-sec ul li a.active span:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: #b60001;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.nav-sec ul li a:hover span {}

.nav-sec ul li a:hover span {
  background-color: #b60001;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-sec ul li a span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.nav-sec ul .nav-drop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open {
  height: 50px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target ul {
  max-height: none;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target a {
  display: block;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #9f0606;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target li:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target li:nth-last-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="nav-sec" id="menu-open">

  <ul class="menu-items" id="menu-closed">

    <li><a href="#" class="active"><span>All</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>MBA</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Bank-PO</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>GK</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Interview</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Miscellaneous</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Vocab</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Academic Zone</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu-closed"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu-open"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span></a></li>
  </ul>

</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have n number of menu items. Few items visible and to make invisible items visible, I use toggle with css. Is it possible to make horizontal scroll on mobile view along with the view more button. User can view the items list using scroll as well as using view more button. Please support

Please refer the URL below:
https://codepen.io/olach/pen/adeMzP
I want the functionality exactly same but with one additional feature i.e. horizontal scroll at the same time to view items. So that user can use either of these methods to access invisible list items.

Comment: please add html code, try to add code rather than images,

Comment: Hi Akhil, Please check now

Answer (score 0):

You was missing couple of css, like

```
nav-sec#menu-open:target li {
    display: block!important;
}
.nav-sec#menu-open:target a {
  display: block;
}
```

The snippet is updated with the css, please check the snippet. :)

```css
.nav-sec {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 994;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-sec a.all {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.nav-sec a.all span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #b60001;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-sec ul.menu-items {
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  max-height: 50px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.nav-sec ul.last-itm {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-sec ul.last-itm ul {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.nav-sec ul.last-itm ul li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-sec ul.last-itm li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.nav-sec ul.last-itm li a {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.nav-sec li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.nav-sec ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

.nav-sec ul li a[href="#menu-open"]:hover span,
.nav-sec ul li a[href="#menu-closed"]:hover span {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000
}

.nav-sec ul li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-sec ul li.last i {
  color: #b60001;
}

.nav-sec ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #000;
}

.nav-sec ul li a.active span {
  background-color: #b60001;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-sec ul li a.active span:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: #b60001;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.nav-sec ul li a:hover span {}

.nav-sec ul li a:hover span {
  background-color: #b60001;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-sec ul li a span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.nav-sec ul .nav-drop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open {
  height: 50px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target ul {
  max-height: none;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #9f0606;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target li {
  display: block;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target a {
  display: block;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target li:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.nav-sec#menu-open:target li:nth-last-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="nav-sec" id="menu-open">

  <ul class="menu-items" id="menu-closed">

    <li><a href="#" class="active"><span>All</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>MBA</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Bank-PO</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>GK</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Interview</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Miscellaneous</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Vocab</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Academic Zone</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Placement Training3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu-closed"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu-open"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span></a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: i have already changed that css as per my requirement. I want my css to exactly in the same manner as you viewed in my snippet. But additionality i want horizontal scroll bar there. So that user can view  the remaining items using touch screen scroll and as well as with toggle.

Comment: @ManishAswal did you check the updated snippet in answer ??

Comment: Yes I did. But this is not the solution i am looking for. Css you have added are only converting a and li  in block. But i want these as inline elements in single row.

Comment: @ManishAswal code box sample has vertical scroll, you want the result in horizontal scroll ??

Comment: Please check my new snippet. I want both functionalities to work together as I mentioned in my snippets.

Comment: I think I have solved the issue to some extent. Please check my latest snippet again, wherein scroll and dropdown are working together . I have changed the css a bit.  But now the issue is to fix the dropdown button on right side.
 .nav-sec { padding: 0;background-color: #fff;border-radius: 3px; margin-top: 20px;box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); position: relative; height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;z-index: 994;float: left;width: 100%;overflow-y: hidden;    overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap; position: relative;}.nav-sec#menu-open:target .menu-items {
    white-space: normal;
}